# apache beam pipeline ingesting "Big" input file (more than 1GB) doesn't create any output file

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Regarding the dataflow model of computation, I'm doing a PoC to test a few concepts using apache beam with the direct-runner (and java sdk). I'm having trouble creating a pipeline which reads a "big" csv file (about 1.25GB) and dumping it into an output file without any particular transformation like in the following code (I'm mainly concerned with testing IO bottlenecks using this dataflow/beam model because that's of primary importance for me):

```
// Example 1 reading and writing to a file
Pipeline pipeline = Pipeline.create();
PCollection<String> output = ipeline
    .apply(TextIO.read().from("BIG_CSV_FILE"));
output.apply(
    TextIO
        .write()
        .to("BIG_OUTPUT")
        .withSuffix("csv").withNumShards(1));
pipeline.run();
```

The problem that I'm having is that only smaller files do work, but when the big file is used, no output file is being generated (but also no error/exception is shown either, which makes debugging harder).

I'm aware that on the runners page of the apache-beam project (https://beam.apache.org/documentation/runners/direct/), it is explicitly stated under the memory considerations point:

> *Local execution is limited by the memory available in your local environment. It is highly recommended that you run your pipeline with
> data sets small enough to fit in local memory. You can create a small
> in-memory data set using a Create transform, or you can use a Read
> transform to work with small local or remote files.*

This above suggests I'm having a memory problem (but sadly isn't being explicitly stated on the console, so I'm just left wondering here). I'm also concerned with their suggestion that the dataset should fit into memory (why isn't it reading from the file in parts instead of fitting the whole file/dataset into memory?)

A 2nd consideration I'd like to also add into this conversation would be (in case this is indeed a memory problem): How basic is the implementation of the direct runner? I mean, it isn't hard to implement a piece of code that reads from a big file in chunks, and also outputs to a new file (also in chunks), so that at no point in time the memory usage becomes a problem (because neither file is completely loaded into memory - only the current "chunk"). Even if the "direct-runner" is more of a prototyping runner to test semantics, would it be too much to expect that it should deal nicely with huge files? - considering that this is a unified model built for the ground up to deal with streaming where window size is arbitrary and huge data accumulation/aggregation before sinking it is a standard use-case.

So more than a question I'd deeply appreciate your feedback/comments regarding any of these points: have you notice IO constraints using the direct-runner? Am I overlooking some aspect or is the direct-runner really so naively implemented? Have you verified that by using a proper production runner like flink/spark/google cloud dataflow, this constraint disapears?

I'll eventually test with other runners like the flink or the spark one, but it feels underwhelming that the direct-runner (even if it is intended only for prototyping purposes) is having trouble with this first test I'm running on - considering the whole dataflow idea is based around ingesting, processing, grouping and distributing huge amounts of data under the umbrella of an unified batch/streaming model.

---

**EDIT (to reflect Kenn's feedback):**
Kenn, thanks for those valuable points and feedback, they have been of great help in pointing me towards relevant documentation. By your suggestion I've found out by profiling the application that the problem is indeed a java heap related one (that somehow is never shown on the normal console - and only seen on the profiler). Even though the file is "only" 1.25GB in size, internal usage goes beyond 4GB before dumping the heap, suggesting the direct-runner isn't "working by chunks" but is indeed loading everything in memory (as their doc says).

Regarding your points:

1- I believe that serialization and shuffling can very well still be achieved through a "chunk by chunk" implementation. Maybe I had a false expectation of what the direct-runner should be capable of, or I didn't fully grasp its intended reach, for now I'll refrain of doing non-functional type of tests while using the direct-runner.

2 - Regarding sharding. I believe the NumOfShards controls the parallelism (and amount of output files) at the write stage (processing before that should still be fully parallel, and only at the time of writing, will it use as many workers -and generate as many files- as explicitly provided). Two reasons to believe this are: first, the CPU profiler always show 8 busy "direct-runner-workers" -mirroring the amount of logical cores that my PC has-, independently on if I set 1 shard or N shards. The 2nd reason is what I understand from the documentation here (https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.0.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/WriteFiles.html) :

> By default, every bundle in the input PCollection will be processed by
> a FileBasedSink.WriteOperation, so the number of output will vary
> based on runner  behavior, though at least 1 output will always be
> produced. **The exact parallelism of the write stage can be controlled**
> **using withNumShards(int),  typically used to control how many files**
> **are produced or to globally limit the number of workers connecting to**
> **an external service. However, this option  can often hurt performance:**
> **it adds an additional GroupByKey to the pipeline.**

One interesting thing here is that "additional GroupByKey added to the pipeline" is kind of undesired in my use case (I only desire results in 1 file, without any regard for order or grouping),
so probbly adding an extra "flatten" files step, after having the N sharded output files generated is a better approach.

3 - your suggestion for profiling was spot on, thanks.

---

**Final Edit** the direct runner is not intended for performance testing, only prototyping and well formedness of the data. It doen't have any mechanism of spliting and dividing work by partitions, and handles everything in memory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few issues or possibilities. I will answer in priority order.

1. The direct runner is for testing with very small data. It is engineered for maximum quality assurance, with performance not much of a priority. For example:

- it randomly shuffles data to make sure you are not depending on ordering that will not exist in production
- it serializes and deserializes data after each step, to make sure the data will be transmitted correctly (production runners will avoid serialization as much as possible)
- it checks whether you have mutated elements in forbidden ways, which would cause you data loss in production

The data you are describing is not very big, and the DirectRunner can process it eventually in normal circumstances.

2. You have specified `numShards(1)` which explicitly eliminates all parallelism. It will cause all of the data to be combined and processed in a single thread, so it will be slower than it could be, even on the DirectRunner. In general, you will want to avoid artificially limiting parallelism.
3. If there is any out of memory error or other error preventing processing, you should see a lot message. Otherwise, it will be helpful to look at profiling and CPU utilization to determine if processing is active.

Comment: thanks for your feedback and for taking time to write a response, I added an edit section on the original post to reflect your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

This question has been indirectly answered by Kenn Knowles above. The direct runner is not intended for performance testing, only prototyping and well formedness of the data. It doen't have any mechanism of spliting and dividing work by partitions, and handles every dataset in memory. Performance testing should be carried on by using other runners (like Flink Runner), - those will provide data splitting and the type of infrastructure needed to deal with high IO bottlenecks.

**UPDATE:** adding to the point adressed by this question, there is a related question here: [How to deal with (Apache Beam) high IO bottlenecks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68206601/how-to-deal-with-apache-beam-high-io-bottlenecks/68527913#68527913)

Whereas the question here revolves around figuring out if the direct runner can deal with huge datasets (*which we already established here that it is not possible*); the provided link above points to a discussion of weather production runners (like flink/spark/cloud dataflow) can deal natively out of the box with huge datasets (the short answer is yes, but please check yourself on the link for a deeper discussion).